# Where to find information about cellphone plans

Tags: discussion

I have a dumb phone and I'm trying to buy my first iPhone. It's been really hard to find answers to the following questions in a comprehensive way:

- does it make more sense to buy a phone, pay the ETF, and just do a month-to-month contract?
- what do contracts for unlocked iPhones look like on different carriers?
- how can I get a good deal on a 2 year contract? are there discounts available?

I understand this might not be the right place to ask; if it isn't I would appreciate a pointer to a place where I could find answers, or ask people who'd know the answers.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the PF & Money SE isn't the right place to ask – that would be considered a *shopping* question, and would be off-topic. Thanks for asking here at meta first.

Since you're interested in the iPhone specifically, I'd suggest finding a U.S.-based iPhone discussion forum where such questions would be on-topic.  Chances are there are many iPhone users who have researched the costs across the U.S.-based carriers already.

Answer (score 1):

http://howardforums.com/ is such a discussion board.  They are also visually the reason why Stack exchanges are popular.

It is hard to read that site without Ad-Block or something to dim the noise.  I don't support ad-block on most sites, but there is one where they go overkill on ad space.